# How do I merge my sequential raw backup images into one single qcow2 image with snapshots?

Tags: snapshot, qcow2

I have collected a number of raw disk image clones from an embedded system over a long time, each about 2 GB:

```
root141221.dd 2048901120
root150221.dd 2048901120
root160408.dd 2048901120
root170821.dd 2048901120
…
```

Since little is changed between the runs, I thought it would be nifty to convert this into a single *qcow2* image with snapshots.

The first step was easy:

```
$ qemu-img convert -p -O qcow2 root141221.dd root.qcow2
$ qemu-img snapshot -c root141221 root.qcow2
$ qemu-img info root.qcow2
image: root.qcow2
file format: qcow2
virtual size: 1.91 GiB (2048901120 bytes)
disk size: 1.89 GiB
cluster_size: 65536
Snapshot list:
ID        TAG               VM SIZE                DATE     VM CLOCK     ICOUNT
1         root141221            0 B 2023-10-04 01:25:52 00:00:00.000          0
Format specific information:
    compat: 1.1
    compression type: zlib
    lazy refcounts: false
    refcount bits: 16
    corrupt: false
    extended l2: false
```

Now what? How do I write the second image to this first qcow2 image, so it will recognize the shared parts an only store the modifications?

I tried `qemu-img dd …` but that overwrote the whole image. I also think there is a way to do it with `qemu-img rebase …` but if I'm not mistaken that will create a new file, although a small file with only the difference. I want it in one single file.

Do I have to use some loop-mount trick? I can't actually *mount* the image since the data is not really a recognizable filesystem, but maybe I can set it up as a block device?